# How to move one dimension of a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix `A` of shape `(480, 640, 3)`, and I would like to use the values to populate another matrix `B`, of shape `(3, 480, 640)`. I've tried `numpy.reshape(A, B.shape)`, but I think this is not doing the trick.

For some context, the 480 and 640 dimensions are the frame height and width of an image, and the 3 dimension is for the color (RGB) values.

(I'm looking for an efficient way of doing this, not a bunch of nested for loops.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want to swap or roll the axes.  Let's start with an 3-D array:

```
>>> mat = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 4, 3)
>>> mat.shape
(2, 4, 3)
```

Now, let's reorder the axes with swapaxes:

```
>>> mat.swapaxes(0, 2).swapaxes(1, 2).shape
(3, 2, 4)
```

Or, let's roll the axes:

```
>>> rolled = np.rollaxis(mat, 2)
>>> rolled.shape
(3, 2, 4)
```

Comment: Awesome! I like the `rollaxis()` verison.